# 3D data point to 2D data point

Tags: c#, graphics, 3d, linear-algebra, gdi

I'm using GDI+ to implement some simple graphics, I've taken the code from this example http://www.vcskicks.com/3d_gdiplus_drawing.php and can get it to do what I want, but I don't understand how it's doing the conversion from 3D data  point to 2D data point:

```
            //Convert 3D Points to 2D
            Math3D.Point3D vec;
            for (int i = 0; i < point3D.Length; i++)
            {
                vec = cubePoints[i];
                if (vec.Z - camera1.Position.Z >= 0)
                {
                    point3D[i].X = (int)((double)-(vec.X - camera1.Position.X) / (-0.1f) * zoom) + drawOrigin.X;
                    point3D[i].Y = (int)((double)(vec.Y - camera1.Position.Y) / (-0.1f) * zoom) + drawOrigin.Y;
                }
                else
                {
                    tmpOrigin.X = (int)((double)(cubeOrigin.X - camera1.Position.X) / (double)(cubeOrigin.Z - camera1.Position.Z) * zoom) + drawOrigin.X;
                    tmpOrigin.Y = (int)((double)-(cubeOrigin.Y - camera1.Position.Y) / (double)(cubeOrigin.Z - camera1.Position.Z) * zoom) + drawOrigin.Y;

                    point3D[i].X = (float)((vec.X - camera1.Position.X) / (vec.Z - camera1.Position.Z) * zoom + drawOrigin.X);
                    point3D[i].Y = (float)(-(vec.Y - camera1.Position.Y) / (vec.Z - camera1.Position.Z) * zoom + drawOrigin.Y);

                    point3D[i].X = (int)point3D[i].X;
                    point3D[i].Y = (int)point3D[i].Y;
                }
            }
```

I've found a couple of resources which discuss conversion from a 3d data point to a 2d one:

- https://amycoders.org/tutorials/3dbasics.html
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometric_projection
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection

However none of these resources seem to detail the maths used in the above example.

I'd be really grateful if someone could point me at the derivation for the maths and/or explain how the above code works.

Comment: the `/ (vec.Z - camera1.Position.Z)` therm is just perspective division by `Z` distance to camera (more distant points are divided more so the object is smaller with distance). The code however does not transform to camera coordinate system so the camera can not rotate just move...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article and code is a bit confusing, indeed. Before we start, let's do some modifications to the rest of the code. Through these modifications, you will probably see what's going on more easily. Let's specify a static camera position. Instead of this weird formula:

```
double cameraZ = -(((anchorPoint.X - cubeOrigin.X) * zoom) / cubeOrigin.X) + anchorPoint.Z;
```

Let's just do this:

```
cameraZ = 200;
zoom = 100;
```

And after that, we keep

```
camera1.Position = new Math3D.Point3D(cubeOrigin.X, cubeOrigin.Y, cameraZ);
```

This will position the camera at a depth of 200 such that its x/y coordinates coincide with the cube center. I'll come back to the meaning of `zoom`.

The camera model uses a perspective projection and a right-handed coordinate system. That means that the camera look in the negative z-direction and things that are far away will appear smaller.

Let's take a closer look at the 3D->2D conversion code step by step:

```
if (vec.Z - camera1.Position.Z >= 0)
```

`vec` is the point that we want to project. A more intuitive way to write that would be:

```
if (vec.Z >= camera1.Position.Z)
```

So, this branch applies to all points that are behind the camera (remember that the camera looks into the negative z-direction). What happens in this branch is a bit hacky. It has nothing to do with real projections. What you actually want to do is to cut off those points (as they are not visibile). Luckily, in the example, none of the points lie behind the camera. So, we don't need to care about this. I'll come back to that later.

Let's continue to the `else` branch.

```
tmpOrigin = ...
```

This variable is not used anywhere, so we can ignore it.

```
point3D[i].X = (float)((vec.X - camera1.Position.X) / (vec.Z - camera1.Position.Z) * zoom + drawOrigin.X);
```

This is the actual projection (I will only consider the `X` part. The same goes for the `Y` part). Let's take a look at the individual parts:

```
vec.X - camera1.Position.X
```

This is the vector from the camera position to the point drawn. Everything left of the camera has a negative coordinate, everything right of the camera has a positive coordinate.

```
vec.Z - camera1.Position.Z
```

This is the negative depth of the camera. Not sure why the negative depth is used here. This will give you a mirrored image. What you actually wanted to do is (due to the camera looking into the negative z-axis)

```
camera1.Position.Z - vec.Z
```

Then,

```
(vec.X - camera1.Position.X) / (vec.Z - camera1.Position.Z)
```

is the perspective divide. The difference vector is scaled by its inverse depth (i.e. far objects become smaller).

```
* zoom
```

This scales the image from world space (which is very small) to image space (convert world units to pixels). The factor is kind of arbitrary (that's why we just specified `100`). More involved camera models use a field of view.

- drawOrigin.X
  And finally, we align the camera center to the `drawOrigin`. Remember that points left of the camera had a negative coordinate. With this, these will get a positive coordinate (but still be left of `drawOrigin`).

  point3D[i].X = (int)point3D[i].X;
  This is just a cast to int.

For the y-coordinate, there is an additional `-`. This turns the y-axis around (in the pixel coordinate system of the image, the y-axis points downwards).

Let's go back to the hacky `if` branch. You see that the formula is exactly the same. Except that the part that had the negative depth of the point before now has `(-0.1f)`. So these points will be considered having a constant depth of `0.1`. Pretty dubious and far from actual projections.

And that's basically it. One more note: The article has a section about Gimbal lock. Thing is, the properties of matrix multiplications that are described there have nothing to do with Gimbal lock. So, don't rely on this article too much. It's a nice practical application, but it has quite some flaws.

Comment: Thanks Nico, very well explained!